# Heroku Deployment Error for Rails app using "postgres" Database

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

while deploying my new rails app into Heroku i am getting these below mentioned error

```
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with blow command.

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL

heroku rake db:migrate

heroku restart
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: hai Hardik, i tried it works good, but i am not able run the deployed app in Browser, saying that "Application error"

Comment: hai hardik, i found issue through "heroku logs", Controller Issue. thanks

Comment: My pleasure..!! :)